# Display the full, not a simplified Checkout page by clicking the "Pay" button in My Account area in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to redirect users to the full, not the simplified Checkout page when they click the "Pay" button in My Account area.

Why is it necessary and important:

- In the main Checkout, the user specified data in custom fields, but they are not displayed in the simplified version of the Checkout;
- The data in the general fields, for example, the "address" and "shipping method" could also change over time, and the minified Checkout does not display them and cannot change them.

What I tried to do:

- I tried to change the "order-pay" endpoint in the WooCommerce settings, but it didn't help;
- I used the following code to remove the `/order-pay/` part from the `/checkout/order-pay/123456/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_ABj0ZXJKb6MBT` URL of the button and send the user to the main checkout, but this code, when clicking on the updated "Pay" button URL, in my case simply redirects the user to the homepage with the `https://www.mywebsite.com/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_ABj0ZXJKb6MBT` URL.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'modify_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 10, 2 );
function modify_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions( $actions, $order ) {
    if( isset( $actions['pay']['url'] ) ) {
        $actions['pay']['url'] = str_ireplace( 'order-pay/', '', $actions['pay']['url'] );
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you require redirection to the complete checkout page, or would you prefer a simplified order pay checkout page that includes all the necessary fields? Would the simplified checkout page be suitable for your needs?